# identify the 3D object in space using laser point sensor and bring its origin wrt laser values

Tags: transformation, robotics

**Description** : we are doing robotic application where i want to know the position of the object with respect to origin

**Purpose of application** : here i am going to teach robot with respect to master piece and next time if object come to work area i am going to alter the robot coordinates system with respect to the object.

Hurdle/ issue : object is coming on conveyor its position may not fix, it may vary in any X, Y and Z plane

**Existing set up** : here i have used 6 point laser sensor that can give me liner distance, using these sensor i should accurately identify the object coordinates same given to robot.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhZT5.png)

graphical represntation as shown in above image

if Object is oriented how can i know its position same can be apply to my robot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xm4Mo.png)

i request any one can help me solve this problem and if you need further information, i willing to give

please help us which equation can help and my method is right or wrong, i am eager to here from you guys

Comment: Some additional questions indeed. (1) What are the shapes of your objects? A cube like in the images? Is the size of the cube known and constant? (2) What are your lasers measuring? The distance from the tip of the laser to the first point of the object hit by the laser? Please update your question accordingly.

Comment: (1) What are the shapes of your objects - is 4 wheeler  Vehicle body                                        Is the size of the cube known and constant -  yes dimensions of object is remain same for all time  (2) What are your lasers measuring - means laser sensor which can give linear distance in mm the distance of all laser pointing on object is settable & is 50 mm

Comment: Please let me know if you need more information on this

Comment: Can any one help in this please